# How do you load a module @everywhere inside a function in Julia

Tags: module, julia, distributed-computing

I am trying to load a module in my workers after creating them with `addprocs`. When `addprocs` is called at the top level, everything is fine. However, I am not able to do the same thing when I wrap the code in a function.

In my case, I am adding workers dynamically, so it is not feasible to call `@everywhere using XXX` always on the top level, I would need to do this inside a function.

In short, this works:

```
addprocs(1)
@everywhere using XXX
```

and this doesn't:

```
function myaddprocs()
    addprocs(1)
    @everywhere using XXX
end
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After a bit more investigation, I have pinpointed some of the issues which were making my code not work.

1. Imports must happen **after** `addprocs`. If an import has happened before, the import must be prefixed by an `@everywhere`.
2. Top-level expressions (such as `using`) inside functions do not work, unless wrapped in an `eval` statement.

A fix to my code would be:

```
function myaddprocs()
    addprocs(1)
    eval(macroexpand(quote @everywhere using XXX end))
end
```

---

### Examples

I have tested the following snippets on Julia 0.6.1. I have also tested them using the same version on a SGE cluster (OGS/GE 2011.11p1), by substituting all `addprocs` by `addprocs_sge`, and importing `ClusterManagers.jl`. The following snippets work:

- `using` after `addprocs`:

  ```
  addprocs(1)
  using SpecialFunctions
  pmap(x->SpecialFunctions.sinint(1), workers())
  ```
- `using` before and after `addprocs`, the second with `@everywhere`:

  ```
  using SpecialFunctions
  addprocs(1)
  @everywhere using SpecialFunctions
  pmap(x->sinint(1), workers())
  ```
- `using` wrapped in `eval` after `addprocs` within function

  ```
  function getprocs()
      addprocs(1)
      eval(Expr(:using,:SpecialFunctions))
      pmap(x->SpecialFunctions.sinint(1), workers())
  end
  getprocs()
  ```
- Same as before with with `@everywhere` applied to `eval`

  ```
  function getprocs()
      addprocs(1)
      @everywhere eval(Expr(:using,:SpecialFunctions))
      pmap(x->sinint(1), workers())
  end
  getprocs()
  ```
- Same as before with with `@everywhere` within `eval` instead

  ```
  function getprocs()
      addprocs(1)
      eval(macroexpand(quote @everywhere using SpecialFunctions end))
      pmap(x->sinint(1), workers())
  end
  getprocs()
  ```

These snippets, on the other hand, do not work:

- `using` before `addprocs`

  ```
  using SpecialFunctions
  addprocs(1)
  pmap(x->SpecialFunctions.sinint(1), workers())
  ```
- `using` before and after `addprocs`

  ```
  using SpecialFunctions
  addprocs(1)
  using SpecialFunctions
  pmap(x->SpecialFunctions.sinint(1), workers())
  ```
- `using` within function

  ```
  using SpecialFunctions
  function getprocs()
      addprocs(1)
      @everywhere using SpecialFunctions
      pmap(x->sinint(1), workers())
  end
  getprocs()
  ```
- `using` within function

  ```
  function getprocs()
      addprocs(1)
      using SpecialFunctions
      pmap(x->SpecialFunctions.sinint(1), workers())
  end
  getprocs()
  ```

Answer (score 2):

you don't need `@everywhere`. this works for me:

```
addprocs()
using mymodule  # loads code on all procs but brings in to scope only on master process.
```

this is what you want if you want to then do `pmap(x->fun(x),workers())`, and `fun` is exported from `mymodule`. you can read this up here: https://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.6/manual/parallel-computing/#Code-Availability-and-Loading-Packages-1

Comment: Hi Florian, you are right, this works! However, I had to use `mymodule.fun`. Unfortunately for me I have just realized that I must also have this work for addprocs_sge from ClusterManagers, and the current solution does not work. I will submit a but report on their project instead. Thanks!

Comment: well if you don't `export fun`, then you have to do `mymodule.fun`. why does `addprocs_sge` not work (*what exactly* does not work)? if you add a reproducible example at the bottom of your question you'll have a better chance of getting help! cheers

Comment: I spent a bit more time sorting thing out and posted my conclusions as an answer. I think everything makes sense now, thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

Cako's solution is helpful but I had to add the module as first argument to macroexpand :

```
eval(macroexpand(Distributed,quote @everywhere using DistributedArrays end))
```